# Package for changing font with each letter?

Tags: fonts

I want to write a text in which each letter uses a different font. It is rather short. I guess I could make it letter by letter, selecting the font I want for each of them.

Are there easier ways?

Comment: Do you care at all which fonts the package chooses?  This is possible (make all letters active!) but weird and I guess more trouble to write the package than to do this by hand.

Comment: An `\everyletter` hook would make this easy.  Could such a thing be done in Luatex?

Comment: @Charles: It should not be hard to write a macro that gives a piece of text certain attribute (luatex attributes) and a function at `pre_linebreak_filter` this assigns nodes with that attribute a random font from a predefined set. But it might be too much work for a one use only feature.

Comment: If the document itself is the text, I'd rather write a Python script that creates the TeX source file (then again, I'm more proficient in Python than in TeX, so YMMV).

Comment: _why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: For effect, in a poster. Not for a whole long text, that's for sure. It would be painful to read a whole page written like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, I'm sure that this could be vastly improved.  In particular, it doesn't like spaces and it doesn't like being fed an argument (so using the `lipsum` package to demonstrate it didn't work).  Of course, the kerning is completely messed up, but then I'd be amazed at a solution that got that right!

[image]

It uses the `fontspec` package, and for some reason unknown to me, to use the proper names of the fonts required me to use `lualatex` instead of `xelatex`.

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newfontfamily\fonta{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\newfontfamily\fontb{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\newfontfamily\fontc{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\newfontfamily\fontd{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\fonte{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily\fontf{TeX Gyre Schola}
\newfontfamily\fontg{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\fonth{GFS Artemisia}
\newfontfamily\fonti{GFS Bodoni}
\newfontfamily\fontj{Iwona}
\newfontfamily\fontk{GFS Didot}
\newfontfamily\fontl{GFS Neohellenic}
\newfontfamily\fontm{Kurier}
\newfontfamily\fontn{Free Mono}
\newfontfamily\fonto{Free Sans}
\newfontfamily\fontp{Free Serif}
\newfontfamily\fontq{Inconsolata}
\newfontfamily\fonts{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\fontt{Cyklop}
\newfontfamily\fontu{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily\fontv{Antykwa Poltawskiego}
\newfontfamily\fontw{STIX General}
\newfontfamily\fontx{Punknova}
\newfontfamily\fonty{Semafor}
\newfontfamily\fontz{UM Typewriter}

\makeatletter
\edef\my@relax{\relax}
\newcommand{\do@font}[1]{%
  \edef\my@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\my@arg\my@relax
  \else
  \@ifundefined{font#1}{}{%
    \csname font#1\endcsname}%
  \my@arg
  \expandafter\do@font
  \fi}

\newcommand{\dofont}[1]{%
  \edef\my@arg{#1}%
  \expandafter\do@font\my@arg\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Large
\dofont{the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\dofont{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

All the fonts are ones that I found in my TeXLive2010 distribution.

Comment: XeLaTeX fonts can only be loaded by name if they are installed in the operating system (Mac) or with fontconfig (Windows/Linux).

Comment: @Will: Thanks!  That's cleared that up for me.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a different approach than what I proposed above, The following lua code is to be saved in a file `randomfont.lua`:

```
function randomfonts(fonts, text)
    local list = { }
    local last, new

    for s in string.gmatch(fonts,"([^, ]+)") do
        list[#list+1] = s
    end

    for c in string.utfcharacters(text) do
        if c:is_empty() then
            tex.sprint(c)
        else
            while last==new do
                new = math.random(#list)
            end
            tex.sprint(luatexbase.catcodetables.latex,
                string.format([[{\%s %s}]], list[new], c))
            last = new
        end
    end
end
```

And a test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,fontspec}
\newfontfamily\one[Color=red]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\two[Color=blue]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily\three[Color=yellow]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\four[Color=green]{TeX Gyre Bonum}

\directlua{dofile("randomfont.lua")} % load the lua file

\newcommand\randomfonts[2]{%
  \directlua{randomfonts("#1", "#2")}%
}

\begin{document}
% can take text strings
\randomfonts{one, two, three, four}{abcdef ghijk lmn o}

% or even macros
\def\sometext{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\randomfonts{one, two, three, four}{\sometext}
\end{document}
```

***Update**: updated to load the lua file just once instead of loading it with each macro invocation.*

***Update 2**: now using `string.utfcharacters(text)` instead of `unicode.utf8.gmatch(text,".")` as the former looks better (it is a luatex extension to lua string library)*

***Update 3**: make the lua code more compact, and make sure next character is always using a different font.*

Comment: Also you seem to be generating (and parsing) the list of fonts `t` each time you produce a single letter. Could you do this only once in the code of `randomfonts`?

Comment: @Juan: right, it was craft for previous, pre-post, iterations, now fixed.

Comment: Nice, but it won't work if the argument isn't purely expandable (say, `\lipsum[1]` for example). So, IMO, the `pre_linebreak_filter` approach would be superior.