# Randomly reusing a custom font for the same letters (On first iteration use custom font no 1, on second iteration use custom font no 2, and so on)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mac, mactex

I have some custom fonts that I have imported to my Font Book (I am using a macOS machine and am using XeTeX).

I can import those custom fonts with the answer written in [Package for changing font with each letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/package-for-changing-font-with-each-letter), but in that answer, it seems that a letter would use a custom font, but it doesn't change when the letter is repeated. I am looking for an answer that would change a letter as its use is iterated.

What do I mean by iterated? Say we are using Helvetica, Courier, and Comic Sans MS. And we are trying to write the sentence "Lorem amet consectetur elit".

- The e in Lorem would use the Helvetica font
- The e in amet would use the Comic Sans MS font
- The e in consectetur would use the Courier font
- The e in elit would use the Helvetica font

The order does not have to follow [Helvetica, Courier, and Comic Sans MS], I would like it to be random. In other words:

- The e in Lorem could use the Comic Sans MS font
- The e in amet could use the Courier font
- The e in consectetur could use the Helvetica font
- The e in elit could use the Courier font

is viable. What I aim to achieve is a document in which the letters of a sentence would randomly use a font style for a letter, and would change as the letter is used again. It does not follow a rigid way of using fonts.

It seems that that case has been answered in [Randomized fonts for handwritten look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532189/randomized-fonts-for-handwritten-look) (see the example image, particularly the `äöüß` part.)

With those answers, I tried to integrate the first answer (fontspec import ttf) into the second answer but it doesn't seem to work out, and would instead just use the default font.

[image: Integrated work]

In that image above, is the result of my integration of those two answers. I did `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `\setmainfont{My-Custom-Font}`, and set `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{fontlist}{{lmr}{lmdh}` into `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{fontlist}{{my-custom-font}{lmdh}`. `my-custom-font` is not the name of the font, just a placeholder.

It does not seem to be working, hence I'm asking this question here, I hope that I would get a viable answer, thank you so much.

PS: I tried to import my font like it was told in [Package for changing font with each letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/package-for-changing-font-with-each-letter), and it did work. I'm just confused as to how I can import my custom font like how I did in the first answer, and into a changing-font-as-it-iterates pattern like written in the second answer, where it seems that it imports the fontcode instead of the fontname (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/font_typefaces).

Once again, thank you so much. I hope I am clear in explaining my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to adapt the answer given in this answer:

- [Randomized fonts for handwritten look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532189/2693)

to use `fontspec` instead of the PSNFSS naming system used by the old fonts.  We just need to change `\rndfont` command to use the name of the font family defined using `\newfontfamily`:

```
\newcommand*{\rndfont}{\pgfmathrandomitem\z{fontlist}\csname\z\endcsname}
```

Then we change the random list to include those names:

```
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{fontlist}{{helvetica}{comic}{courier}}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}
\newfontfamily\helvetica{Helvetica}
\newfontfamily\comic[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Comic Sans MS}
\newfontfamily\courier{Courier}

\usepackage{censor}


\makeatletter


\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textrndfont}{\rndfont}
\newcommand*{\rndfont}{\pgfmathrandomitem\z{fontlist}\csname\z\endcsname}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{fontlist}{{helvetica}{comic}{courier}}

\def\stringend{$}


\long\def\randomfont#1{%
\protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
\def~{-}\expandafter\random@Block\tmp\stringend\let~\sv@tilde}
\long\def\random@Block{\IfNextToken\stringend{\@gobble}%
  {\IfNextToken\@sptoken{ \bl@t{\random@Block}}%
  {\bl@t{\random@Block}}}}

\long\def\bl@t#1#2{%
\ifx\bpar#2\let\next\par\else\def\next{\textrndfont{#2}}\fi
  \next#1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\randomfont{This text should be in random fonts äöüß.  It's quite long and should line wrap.  I wonder what happens if it has a double blank line in it.


Let's find out whether it starts a new paragraph at the beginning of this sentence. Yes}

\randomfont{This text should be in random fonts äöüß}\par


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is there anyway that I could apply \randomfont to all texts? Because by default the randomness of the font selection is the point of it, and using \randomfont for each time I would want to use it would seem to be counter productive. Thank you.

Comment: @RogerStach No, there's no way for it to work that way, given how to code is designed.